# Can I reskin a Tabaxi as a canine in AL?

Tags: dnd-5e, dnd-adventurers-league, tabaxi

Would it be legal in Adventurer's league to play a Tabaxi, that I called a wolf?

I want to play an anthro-canine, but seeing as there is no official race of that sort, would it be considered legal to use the play a Tabaxi, that looked like and was a dog equivalent? I plan to use the Tabaxi stats as-is otherwise without modifications.

Comment: @nick012000 Please chill out a bit. Your comments here were a bit rude and have been removed; let people enjoy the things they like and leave that be, and please do not throw entire subcommunities of our hobby under the bus.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The Adventurers League FAQ addresses a question about exactly this topic: reskinning races. You can find the latest version in the ["D&D Adventurers League DM & Player Pack" on DMsGuild](https://www.dmsguild.com/product/208178/DD-Adventurers-League-Players-Pack); the current version as of this answer is FAQ v9.1.

The relevant guidance appears on page 6 of that version of the document. You can also find the same answer on [page 7 of the FAQ v9.0 PDF](https://media.wizards.com/2019/dnd/downloads/DDAL_FAQv9.pdf#page=7) on Wizards of the Coast's website. (As indicated by the [changelog for v9.1](https://dndadventurersleague.org/al-campaign-rules-updates-january-2020/), the update adds some other sections that don't appear in v9.0, but the guidance on this topic is unchanged.)

In the "Races & Classes" section, below the heading "Reskinning Races", it states:

> You may reskin your race (playing a rare elf subrace, for example) if you choose, but have the traits of a normally available subrace (high elf, etc.); the character creation process doesn’t change.  Your DM may disallow this if they feel it inappropriate.

Ultimately, as long as you're just reflavoring the race without changing any mechanics, the DM can choose to allow or disallow your proposed reflavoring of the race. (Any mechanical changes based on your reflavoring would not be allowed.)